# Creating a database in Firebird using FireDac (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I recently changed from AnyDac to FireDac (8.0.5.3365). We're running Delphi 2006.

When I was using the AnyDac version of this component I could create a new database by doing the following..

Setup my connection

```
fConnection.LoginPrompt := false;
fConnection.ResourceOptions.SilentMode := true;

fConnection.Params.Clear;
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('DriverID=%s',          ['IB']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('Database=%s',          [fConnectionInfo.xDatabase]));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('CharacterSet=%s',      ['UTF8']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('user_name=%s',         [fConnectionInfo.xUserName]));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('password=%s',          [fConnectionInfo.xPassword]));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('ExtendedMetadata=%s',  ['True']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('CreateDatabase=%s',    ['Yes']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('Protocol=%s',          ['Local']))

//database path = C:\Users\LoginName\AppData\Local\AppName\TestDB.FDB
```

Open and close the connection

```
fConnection.Open;
fConnection.Close;
```

And then I could run my create table sql scripts on the existing database.

But now when I do this with the FireDac version, the Open command raises the fbe_unavailable error as if I didn't specify the CreateDatabase parameter.

Should I be doing this a different way?

Thanks for your time.

Corey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a full example here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Executing_SQL_Scripts_%28FireDAC%29

For example, the following Firebird script creates a database, and can be executed using TFDScript:

```
SET SQL DIALECT 3;
SET NAMES UTF8;
SET CLIENTLIB 'C:\fb25\bin\fbclient.dll';
CREATE DATABASE 'E:\Test2.ib'
  USER 'sysdba' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
  PAGE_SIZE 16384
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET NONE;

SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC RETURNS (aParam INTEGER) AS
BEGIN
  aParam = 10;
END^
```

You should use CreateDatabase=Yes connection definition parameter
additionally to other required parameters:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Connect_to_Firebird_(FireDAC)