# Difficulties creating a Firebird database in Delphi

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe8, firedac

***clarification***
*David thinks this is a duplicate. I'm aware of that other question, I'm referring to the answer there. It just doesn't solve my problem; for instance I don't see the `CreateDatabase` property in the Object Inspector.*

I am acquainted with Delphi, but this is the first time I need a database in a project. Using Delphi XE8.

In [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21314498/66056) I found a script to create a database, which I used verbatim:

```
SET SQL DIALECT 3;
SET NAMES UTF8;
SET CLIENTLIB 'C:\fb25\bin\fbclient.dll';
CREATE DATABASE 'D:\MyProject.fdb'
  USER 'sysdba' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
  PAGE_SIZE 16384
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET NONE;

SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC RETURNS (aParam INTEGER) AS
BEGIN
  aParam = 10;
END^
```

But I'm having problems with `FDConnection1`. In its `parameters` I entered a database filename, but I don't see the `CreateDatabase` property said answer mentions. When I execute

> FDScript1.ExecuteAll;

nothing happens.

How can I create my database? And where can I set `CreateDatabase=yes`?

**edit 1: What I tried**
I created a VCL application with a TFDScript (`FDScript1`) and a TFDConnection (`FDConnection1`). I entered the above script in the `FDScript1.SQLScripts` property and assigned `FDConnection1` to its `Connection` property.
For `FDConnection1` I set `DriverName` to "FB", entered a `ConnectionName` and entered a filename (full path) in `params.database`.

David points out that my assumption that `CreateDatabase` would be a Property is wrong. Should this then be in the script? (It does already say "CREATE DATABASE".)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a database in Firebird using FireDac (Delphi)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312811/creating-a-database-in-firebird-using-firedac-delphi)

Comment: This is a slam dunk dupe of the question you linked to. Read the answer. Nowhere does it suggest you use TFDConnection to execute SQL. So read the answer carefully. Follow the links. Read them. Do what it says. You need to pay close attention to what is written.

Comment: The answer at the dupe doesn't talk about the Object Inspector, unless I mis-read it. Can you point out the section where it describes setting properties of `TFDConnection` in the Object Inspector. What I see is information about using `TFDScript`. If you have information about how you have setup the `Connection` property of your `TFDScript` please share it. If the question is asking to solve your specific attempt to follow the instructions, provide exact details of your steps so far.

Comment: Parameters go in `Params` I think: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.Params

Comment: @David: Yes, these `params` seem to be a TStringList, though you can also assign the values through the Object Inspector, or as object members in code: `FDConnection1.Params.Database := 'D:\myproject\dakota2.fdb';`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @David: BTW, adding "Createdatabase=yes" to `Params` and then setting the `Connected` property to true results in an "unavailable database" error, i.e. the database still isn't created.

Answer (score 0):

The **CreateDatabase** connection definition parameter has been replaced by [**OpenMode**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Connect_to_Firebird_(FireDAC)#Connection_Definition_Parameters) parameter. I'd would suggest setting it to **OpenOrCreate** in your case (which creates database if doesn't exist, or uses the existing one):

```
...
FDConnection1.Params.Add('OpenMode=OpenOrCreate');
FDConnection1.Connected := True;
```

For FireDAC shipped with Delphi XE7 or below, use the mentioned [**CreateDatabase**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Connect_to_Firebird_(FireDAC)#Connection_Definition_Parameters) parameter.